# sendKeys() method is not sending the keys

Tags: java, selenium

below mentioned is my code, which is not sending the keys to the textbox, however it finds the correct element as the cursor keeps blinking in the textbox.

```
public class cl01 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
     String P1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
     System.out.println(P1);

    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> W = windows.iterator();

    while(W.hasNext())
    {
        String C1 = W.next();
        System.out.println(C1);
        if(!P1.equalsIgnoreCase(C1))
        {
          driver.switchTo().window(C1).close();
        }
    }
   driver.switchTo().window(P1);

   System.out.println("web page opened");

    //Browser's position is set
   driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(30, 40));
   int height = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
   System.out.println( "height of the browser is " +height);

   int width = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
   System.out.println("width of the browser is " +width);

   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a Rediffmail account")).click();
   System.out.println("sign up link opened");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

Comment: where do you send keys? cant find in your code. Ahh just saw it at the end. I think you just have the wrong element and you only think its the right one. sendKeys is working very stable since years. I would guess your interpretation of what should happen is wrong. The code exactly does as it should

Comment: I understand you are trying to access rediff.com. Can you provide me with the HTML DOM so that I can help you. Please update the DOM within the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. Maybe it's slow to load and you need to add a wait for the first element.

I would avoid using XPath in cases like this, especially when the nested layers are so deep and you are relying on indexes. It makes for a very brittle locator. I would use a CSS selector like the below.

```
By.cssSelector("input[name^='name']")
```

I tested this and it worked for me. It's basically looking for an `INPUT` tag that has a name that starts with "name". The name ends with what looks like an automatically generated string but this part is unique on the page.

Here are some references to learn CSS selectors. CSS selectors are really powerful and it's time well spent to learn them.

[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selectors Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

Comment: I have used xpath method with explicit wait, but don't know any thing why this xpath was not working, even if the xpath is correct. I have used following code : `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/..//following::tr/td/input[@name='name9e6f78ab']"))));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/..//following::tr/td/input[@name='name9e6f78ab']")).sendKeys("ABC");`

Comment: When I execute your code, it works fine for me. :) Can you suggest me from where i can learn `cssSelector`?`

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!